# Subaru WRX 2015 whining noise when accelerating and sometimes after gear engaging

Tags: noise, subaru, wrx

### Basic information

- No modifications,
- Clocked 180,000km,
- Only **7 months left** under extended warranty,
- Up to date on log book service,
- I am the original owner.

#### Vehicle performance

- There are no noticeable gear changing issues, like the resistance of the gearbox during gear changes are no different.
- The clutch doesn't feel like it's slipping or catching,
- the engine does not stall when changing gears,
- the vehicle's acceleration is still excellent.

### How I can reproduce the noise and duration

When taking off from stopped position or immediately after accelerating after a gear at low speeds (0-40km/h range) there is a noticeable whining noise that comes from the engine bay.

- (high pitch and almost as if two pieces of sheet metal are rubbing & rattling into each-other) .

The noise lasts only a few seconds and doesn't occur when changing gears while travelling over 40km/h.

I have raised this as an issue during the vehicle's last scheduled service. The mechanic only identified a possible cause as the Rear Hubs (Part [28473VA000](https://parts.subaru.com/p/Subaru__/HUB-UNIT-COMPL/60015296/28473VA000.html)) but that has nothing to do with the noise coming from the engine bay. The Rear Hubs have been replaced under warranty however the noise is still there.

Anyone know what could be causing this or what I should get them to check? I need to sort this out before the extended warranty runs out and the problem gets worse.

Comment: have you tested the alternator belt and alternator bearings of your car.

Comment: Can you reproduce the noise with the car in neutral, or does it only happen in gear?

Comment: I am trying to figure out which whining you could mean - all of my Subarus have whined under heavy acceleration, and more so when I had a track rod issue (I assume differential was the cause in that case) - can you get a recording of the noise?